# how to get real name in Asmack

Tags: android, asmack

How can you get the real name of a message's sender?

Somebody told me its:

```
connection.getAccountAttribues("name");
```

but it returns my own nick name, not the targets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know recipient's name, probably the best way is find in Roster that specific contact and you will get RosterEntry. Now you can call RosterEntry.getName(). The other way is to get this info from Chat object, simply calling Chat.getParticipant(). I hope thats is what are you looking for.